# Editing SharePoint 2013 Pages- Master Pages , Addition of responsive elements within the site

Tags: 2013, css, html, pages, font-awesome

Good Morning. I am stuck at a point in SP 2013 the version is online.

I have been tasked with creating a list of events with some elements within them.  But I have to create them in a richer format than what SharePoint offers I have now tried for the last 5 hours to get font awesome to work as this seems a option but I cant get it to work I have created master pages etc but nothing works.

I am a SharePoint familiar person but my coding isn't the strongest. but I am determined to learn. Can anyone assist please?

I have tried shareboot , fontawesome , placing the  in a script editor webpart. embedding it.

I would ideally like to create a minimalist view for these events using flat icons in a responsive page.

I appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: do you want to do something like this?
http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2013/07/how-to-use-icon-fonts-with-sharepoint/

Comment: Hi yes that is what i am aiming for i have been on the fontello site i am struggling to understand where these snippets of code get added though it rejects when i add it into the embed code section or just doesn't appear

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what steps involved in the deploying third party SharePoint responsive themes.

I would like to give you some steps which I have followed to build the responsive website using Bootstrap.

Here are the references added in my master page which helps to convert complete site responsive.

[image]

Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Thank you for the comment do i just add the code in editing out or substituting your site links with my own ?

Comment: This is guidance to add your references to your master page. In my case, I am using bootstrap for my responsive website. All my JavaScript libraries and CSS files located in my Site Assets library. In your case, you might be stored in different place.